# Kivy: what package name should I use for .jar files added with add_jars?

Tags: kivy, pyjnius

1) In my kivy's project I created `\platforms\android\test.java` with following content:

```
class Test {
    public int test() {
        return 300;
    }
}
```

And compiled it to `.jar` file (in same directory).

2) In `buildozer.spec` I added line:

```
android.add_jars = %(source.dir)s/platforms/android/*.jar
```

3) In projects `main.py` I'm trying to use it:

```
import logging
from kivy.utils import platform

if platform == "android":
    from jnius import autoclass, cast

    Test = autoclass('test.Test')
    logging.info(Test().test())
```

4) apk builds fine, but I get error:

> jnius.jnius.JavaException: Class not found 'test/Test'

I assume problem with package name I used `autoclass('test.Test')`. 
What name should I use to make things work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding `.jar` file it's easier to add `java` source file that p4a will handle to be used on Android.

1) We have file

```
/java_folder/some/test.java
```

with following content:

```
package some;

class Test {
    public int test() {
        return 300;
    }
}
```

2) In `buildozer.spec` we add:

```
android.add_src = %(source.dir)s/java_folder/
```

3) In projects:

```
autoclass('some.Test')
```

works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have some editings in your solution:

1. /java_folder/some/test.java => /java_folder/some/Test.java
2. class Test { => public class Test {

After that all will be work.

Comment: Pleawe provide a link to the answer you are building this on. Otherwise you risk losing the reference once there is more than one other.